# Add repositories to Ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: server, apt, software-sources

I just booted 1st time into Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS (no GUI), enabled UFW, went to update with `sudo apt-get update` and the results showed this:

```
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64    (20140722.3) Trusty InRelease
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3) Trusty/main Translation-en_CA
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3) Trusty/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3) Trusty/restricted Translation-en_CA
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3) Trusty/restricted Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

This is not what I expected to see. In my current desktop environment there is a long list that scrolls past in the terminal.

I assume that there are no repositories listed in the `/etc/apt/source.list` (haven't figured out how to read contents of that file yet)

What should I do?

Comment: The content of `/etc/apt/source.list` would be very useful indeed. If you don't have a GUI, you can [upload it to a pastie from command line](https://clbin.com/): `curl -F 'clbin=</etc/apt/source.list' https://clbin.com`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and added the repository link:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
```

I edited the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and removed the cdrom upgrade source using:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now I can update and install more packages.

Answer (score 0):

The file which lists out the repositories is `sources.list`. You can check its contents by keying in 
`cat /etc/apt/sources.list` 
into the terminal